# Understanding Monero addresses in the wallet GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, sub-address, account

I tried to read a Monero guide but I don't understand some things.

I have addresses that start with `4wzx`, `8AAA` and `8sgs` in Accounts and `8AAA` and `8gjm` in Receive. Why are `8AAA` and `8AAA` the same, but `8sgs` and `8gjm` different? To which address will money belong if someone sends Monero to the `8gjm` subaddress?

Can I send money to the Accounts subaddress and the other address? Or maybe I should use only Receive subaddresses?

What's the difference between Accounts subaddresses and Receive subaddresses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A wallet has a primary address (that starts with a `4`) and can have any number of subaddresses (that start with an `8`). Accounts are just an abstraction which allow subaddresses to be separated - you could create one account for your savings and one for daily spending for example.

When someone sends you XMR to an address, it is sent to that address. The *wallet* that the address belongs to can then spend the received XMR.